# how can I sort alphanumerically ignoring non alphanumeric characters?

Tags: java

I am reading a text file that contains lines with a mix of alphanumeric characters and non-alphanumeric characters. My guess is something like removing the non alphanumeric characters and sorting then putting them back I am not sure how to do that or if that's a good way.

Before sort:

```
Hello
alpha
#%Alpha
--781
hello
```

After sort:

```
--781
#%Alpha
Hello
alpha
hello
```

current code doing the sorting:
List sortedLines = Files.lines(f.toPath()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

This sorts but it is putting #%Alpha before --781 and I am not sure how to remedy this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to define a custom comparator and use it.

Comment: From this two which one comes first ? `#%Alpha , AApha`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String#replaceAll` to remove all non-alphanumeric characters when sorting.

```
List<String> sortedLines = Files.lines(f.toPath())
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I would have to re-add those characters because they need to stay in the line, how would you suggest handling that use case?

Comment: @dmc94 You don't have to add the characters back. It only removes them when comparing. Try it.

Comment: you legend. thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Collections.sort and define a custom comparator such as following :

```
private static List<String> sort(List<String> inputList){
    Collections.sort(inputList, (s1, s2) -> s1.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").compareTo(s2.replaceAll("[^a-bA-Z0-9]", "")));
    return inputList;
}
```